# ERROR: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' - Taurus

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter, taurus

Im working with JMeter and Taurus to run a couple of .jmx test created from JMeter, but when I run the following command:

`bzt xxxxx.jmx -report`

I got this error:

```txt
14:50:54 INFO: Taurus CLI Tool v1.12.0
14:50:54 INFO: Starting with configs: ['C:\\Users\\excmapi\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\jmx_cm6_v7pt.json']
14:50:54 INFO: Configuring...
14:50:54 INFO: Artifacts dir: \Downloads\2018-06-29_14-50-54.858323
14:50:54 INFO: Preparing...
14:50:55 ERROR: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 289636: character maps to <undefined>
  File "\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\bzt\cli.py", line 249, in perform
    self.engine.prepare()
  File "\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\bzt\engine.py", line 169, in prepare
    self.__prepare_provisioning()
  File "\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\bzt\engine.py", line 515, in __prepare_provisioning
    self.provisioning.prepare()
  File "\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\bzt\modules\provisioning.py", line 72, in prepare
    executor.prepare()
  File "\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\bzt\modules\jmeter.py", line 267, in prepare
    scenario = self.get_scenario()
  File "\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\bzt\modules\jmeter.py", line 209, in get_scenario
    script_content = fds.read()
  File "\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
14:50:55 INFO: Post-processing...
14:50:55 INFO: Artifacts dir: \Downloads\2018-06-29_14-50-54.858323
14:50:55 WARNING: Done performing with code: 1
```

The line which give the error are a lot. One of they is the next:

```txt
<elementProp name="&#x1;&#x80;&#x1;&#x82;&#x1;&#x84;I&#x0;D&#x0;_&#x0;1&#x0;{o&#x0;m&#x0;R&#x0;|&#x1;i&#x1;}&#x1;s&#x1;" elementType="HTTPArgument">
```

I've search a lot in internet, but I dont find a solution for this issue. One of the possible cause of this issue which I finded is that when the .jmx file is created, some tags have correlation, so when I want to run the script with Taurus (Python), the console display that issue.
[Here the link](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter)

One of the solution for this issue is using a tool of Blazemeter which you can see in the mentioned link what allow to create a proxy and record the test, but it isn't work to me, because I want to solve this issue without another tool.
Exist some way to fix this then the jmx script was created without add more configuration in JMeter?
I hope you can help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello, any feedback on answer ? it looks like it’s correct, so it should be at minimum accepted to be useful to others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your title issue , There is a bug in Taurus, see:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/codename-taurus/p2J1fpx04KI

Could you try the latest snapshot and report result?
(http://gettaurus.org/docs/DeveloperGuide/)

Comment: I tried using that but not works. The problem is that being web sites, some tags they are dynamic, thus when start the test, they tags can't found, so return a error. This not happens when the tags are statics. Like I said in my question, exist a Blazemeter tool called "proxy recorder" that have a tool called "smart jmx" that fix all of the correlations (tags dynamics).
The same to loadrunner, that allow to fix the correlation

Comment: my answer was only about the taurus error in in the question title, which id due to a bug.I don’t understand the other question, you should ask a new one reformulating it. On stackoverflow, a question must only contain one and be as clear as possible. I updated my answer to make it clear what you need to do for the Taurus bug, you need to get the current master and test. Or if you can share you failing file, I could do the test. Thanks